# What is the purpose of の in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

"このテレビの直し方わかりますか。" means "Do you know how to fix this TV?" but I can't figure out the purpose of の (after テレビ) in this sentence.

Comment: Slipping the 「が」 back in there will show it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

直し方 is a noun meaning "way to fix", or "method of fixing".

The usage of の here is possessive:

> `A` の `B`
>   The `B` of (or belonging to) `A`

So the translation works as follows:

> この　|　テレビ　|　の　|　直し方　|　わかります　|　か
>   This　| 　 TV　　 |　's　 | way to fix | 　(you) know　|　?

Answer (score 1):

It is the most common usage of -no: genitive. It connects the two noun phrases: 1) kono terebi and 2) naosikata. Yes, naosikata is a noun, not a verb which I suspect is your confusion.